# django generic relation delete performance

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a project with two genericrelation in a model. I discover that the relations are useless and moreover therea 3 million records that we don't need anymore. Is there any way do delete it fast?

Remove the field on migrations has no effect because is generic.

So I tried

```
import time

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from app.core import models as m

# UserInformation has a GenericRelation with Address

c = m.UserInformation.objects.first()
c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(c)

# get all the models records generic related with UserInformation
query = m.Address.objects.filter(content_type_id=c_type.id)

start = time.time()
i=0
stop_iteration = 10
for user in query:
    i += 1
    user.delete()
    if i == stop_iteration:
       break

end = time.time()
seconds = end - start
print('Execution of %s deletes: %3d seconds' % (stop_iteration, seconds))
```

The result:

```
Execution of 10 deletes: 34 seconds
```

This means that it will takes 37 days to delete ~1million records

Is there any way to do that quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic relation is defined by a `content_type` and an `object_id`. If you know the `content_type` you can find all `object_id` values and delete them in one query. I don't know the fields in your model but it should be something like this.

```
# get all related object ids
object_ids = m.Address.objects.filter(content_type_id=c_type.id)\
            .values_list('object_id', flat=True)

# delete them in one query 
YourModel.objects.filter(id__in=object_ids).delete()
```